# I can't get this highcharts code to work, does anybody know why it isn't working?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

https://jsfiddle.net/w36qfgds/6/

Short explenation: javascript gets arrays from the table. One combined array of column 1 to 4 with the dates for xAxis (month, day, year, hour - going to change that later to days only) and an array from the last column of the table with the amounts sold.

Looks like it should be working but it doesn't? I've been messing around a bit trying to get it to work but without any result. Does anybody know what's up?

Thanks

```
    //converting the first table columns to xaxis label
  var colValsM = $('table:first td:nth-child(1)').map(function(){
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
    var colValsD = $('table:first td:nth-child(2)').map(function(){
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
    var colValsY = $('table:first td:nth-child(3)').map(function(){
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
  var colValsH = $('table:first td:nth-child(4)').map(function(){
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
  //the amount sold
    var colValsChart = $('table:first td:nth-child(6)').map(function(){
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
    var colDate = [];
    var rowCount = $('table:first').find('tr').length;
  //combine day, month, year and hour
    for (i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        colDate[i] = colValsD[i] + "/" + colValsM[i] + "/" + colValsY[i] + " (" + colValsH[i] + "h)"
    }
console.log(colDate);
console.log(colValsChart);

//Highcharts
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
            type: 'line',
            zoomType: 'x'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Demand'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: colDate,
            labels:{
                step: 72,
                rotation: 315
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Amount'
            }
        },
        legend: {
                enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                enableMouseTracking: true
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Sales',
            data: colValsChart
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your colValsChart is an array of strings.  It needs to be numbers.
Parse those strings into numbers and it works fine.
https://jsfiddle.net/w36qfgds/9/

```
var colValsChart = $('table:first td:nth-child(6)').map(function(){
    return parseInt($(this).text(),10);
}).get();
```

By the way, highcharts can create a chart from an html table input.  It might be an easier solution http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-parsed/